# Array in React state won't map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this setting the state:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    loginShowing: false,
    user: null,
    programs: ['cool','guy','nice']
  }
}
```

... But when I try to do this in the render

```
{this.state.programs.map(program =>
  <h1>{program}</h1>
)}
```

Nothing shows up on the page. If I put `asdf: '123'` in the state and then print `<h1> {this.state.asdf} </h1>`, it does work. Does anybody know why mapping from the array in the state doesn't render? Thanks.

I'm running react on macOS Sierra 10.12.6, with react ^15.6.1.

Edit: it seems that this is the code causing it:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('accountData') != null) {
      this.authenticateToken(localStorage.getItem('accountData'));
    }
  }
```

I don't know how this is affecting the render but it is.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and worked for me:

```
class CustomInput extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    loginShowing: false,
    user: null,
    programs: ['cool','guy','nice']
  }
}

  render() {
     return <div>
     {this.state.programs.map(program =>
        <h1>{program}</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jmfafj

Comment: It seems like it's correct but simply wont render for me. I also then try to pass it into a component as a prop and it passes blank. Peculiar.

Comment: Did you see the stackblitz link? I wonder what's wrong at your end. Can you share more code/settings?

Comment: Yes. When I just have that code in the render, i see it flash for a second without disappearing. No error, just console warning for keys.

Comment: Huh, commented out this code : ```componentDidMount() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('accountData') != null) {
      this.authenticateToken(localStorage.getItem('accountData'));
    }
  }``` and it shows. When i add it back it doesn't

Comment: got it. im an idiot. the authenticate token function resets the state

Comment: @Umesh As I can see the topic starter provided answer for his question by himself. Not in your post nor in the comments I don't see that you provided the answer. Why do you ask to mark your answer as the correct one?

Comment: my bad ! @AlexanderElgin

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your setup. If you're running this code on codepen, you need to have Babel installed. Check the browser console for any error(s).

Here's the [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXxEVR?editors=1010).

Working code -

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    loginShowing: false,
    user: null,
    programs: ['cool','guy','nice']
  }
}
  render() {
    const items = this.state.programs.map(program =>
     <h1>{program}</h1>
    )
    return (
      <div>{items}</div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Foo/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The state was overwriting the mocked programs with an api call in another function.